# Showing Lyapunov (Lindeberg) condition holds for sum of independent bernoulli distribution with poisson tail probability

Tags: mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem, bernoulli-distribution

I'm trying to find an asymptotic distribution of the follwing random variable

$$Z_n=\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i$$ where $Y_i = I[T_i<t]$ with $T_i \text{~} Gamma(i, \lambda)$.

Here $t$ is a fixed number.

My initial trial was using Linderberg CLT by using the Lyapunov CLT ( or Linderberg CLT). First I noticed that by using integral by parts,

$$E[Y_i]=P[Y_i=1]=P[T_i<t]=\sum_{k=i}^\infty \frac{(t/\lambda)^ie^{-t/\lambda}}{i!}$$

which is the tail probabilty of the poisson random variable with mean $t/\lambda$.

Let $p_i:=E[Y_i], R_i:=Y_i-p_i, S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^nR_i, \sigma_n^2:=Var(S_n)=\sum_{i=1}^np_i(1-p_i)$.

I'm trying to show that $R_i$ satisfies the Lyapunov condition where

$$ \sigma_n^{-(2+\delta)}\sum_{i=1}^nE[|R_i|^{(2+\delta)}]\to0\ \text{as $n\to \infty$ }$$.

With $\delta=1$,

I get

$$E[|R_i|^3]=(1-p_i)^3p_i + p_i^3(1-p_i)^3\le p_i(1-p_i)$$ therefore

$$\sigma_n^{-3}\sum_{i=1}^nE[|R_i|^{3}] \le \sigma_n^{-1}.$$

**As long as I can show that $$\sigma_n \to \infty \ \text{as $n\to \infty$ }$$**

I'm done with the proof. But I'm stuck with showing the divergence of $\sigma_n$.

**In other words, I need to show that**

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(1-p_i) \to \infty \ \text{as $n\to \infty$ }.$$

I sincerely ask to help me with the proof of the last statement. Or Am i doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What parametrization are you using for the Gamma distribution? Shape - scale or shape-rate? It would be good to always clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your treatment appears sound.

The following is improvisation, so most likely it is inefficient. It transforms your question to a simpler one, that of convergence of a sequence.

I will assume $\lambda =1$ to simplify notation. The assumption is inconsequential.

The symbol $p_i$ represents the cumulative distribution function of a Gamma distribution with integer shape parameter equal to $i$, i.e. of an Erlang distribution. We have

$$p_i = e^{-t}\sum_{m=i}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!}, \;\;p_{i+1} = e^{-t}\sum_{m=i+1}^\infty \frac{t^m}{m!},$$

$$p_{i+1} = p_i - \pi_i,\;\;\; \pi_i \equiv e^{-t}\frac{t^i}{i!},\;\;\; \pi_i\to 0 \;\text {as}\; i\to \infty$$

By the monotone converge Theorem, it also follows that $p_i$ will go to zero at the limit, and one can deduce that $p_i(1-p_i)$ will go to zero too.

So

$$p_{i+1}\left(1-p_{i+1}) = ( p_i - \pi_i ) (1- p_i + \pi_i) = p_i(1-p_i) -\pi_i(1-2p_i+\pi_i\right)$$

Using this we can decompose the sum we are interested in in two different ways, and we will use both:
\begin{align}
p_2(1-p_2) &= p_1(1-p_1) - \pi_1(1-2p_1+\pi_1) \\
p_3(1-p_3) & = p_2(1-p_2) - \pi_2(1-2p_2+\pi_2) \\
&= p_1(1-p_1) - \pi_1(1-2p_1+\pi_1) - \pi_2(1-2p_2+\pi_2)\\
etc
\end{align}
Using the first equality, i.e. simply going one index value back we get

$$\sum_{i=1}^n p_i(1-p_i) = p_1(1-p_1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i(1-p_i) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\pi_i(1-2p_i+\pi_i)$$

and canceling out and rearranging, we get the expression

$$p_1(1-p_1) = p_n(1-p_n) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\pi_i(1-2p_i+\pi_i) \tag{1}$$

Now if we decompose every $p_i(1-p_i)$ element down to an expression involving $p_1(1-p_1)$, as we indicatively did for $p_3(1-p_3)$ previously we get 
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n p_i(1-p_i) &= np_1(1-p_1) - (n-1)\pi_1(1-2p_1+\pi_1) \\ 
&- (n-2)\pi_2(1-2p_2+\pi_2)-...-\pi_{n-1}(1-2p_{n-1}+\pi_{n-1}) \tag{2}
\end{align}

Use expression $(1)$ to substitute for $p_1(1-p_1)$ in the right-hand-side of expression $(2)$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n p_i(1-p_i) &= n\cdot\Big[p_n(1-p_n) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\pi_i(1-2p_i+\pi_i)\Big] - (n-1)\pi_1(1-2p_1+\pi_1) \\ 
&- (n-2)\pi_2(1-2p_2+\pi_2)-...-\pi_{n-1}(1-2p_{n-1}+\pi_{n-1}) \\
\\\implies \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(1-p_i) &= np_n(1-p_n) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\Big(i\cdot \pi_i(1-2p_i+\pi_i)\Big) \tag{3}
\end{align}

We are interested in

$$\text{lim}_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n p_i(1-p_i) = \text{lim}_{n\to \infty}\Big[np_n(1-p_n)\Big] + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\Big(i\cdot \pi_i(1-2p_i+\pi_i)\Big) \tag{4}$$

Use selectively the expression for $\pi_i$ and apply the Ratio Test for the convergence of the infinite series:

$$\text{lim}_{i\to \infty}\left(\frac{(i+1)\cdot e^{-t}\frac{t^{i+1}}{(i+1)!}(1-2p_{i+1}+\pi_{i+1})}{i\cdot e^{-t}\frac{t^i}{i!}(1-2p_i+\pi_i)}\right)
$$

$$t\cdot\text{lim}_{i\to \infty}\left(\frac{(i+1)\cdot (1-2p_{i+1}+\pi_{i+1})}{i\cdot(i+1) (1-2p_i+\pi_i)}\right) \to 0 <1.
$$

...because the terms in parentheses go to unity. So the infinite series in expression $(4)$ is absolutely convergent. Therefore, whether the sum of interest converges or diverges hints on the limit of the sequence $\{np_n(1-p_n)\}$.

**Comment:** after obtaining that the series $\{p_i(1-p_i)\}$ is monotonically declining, it would be trivial  to realize that

$$np_n(1-p_n) < \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(1-p_i)$$
and so that if we could determine that $\{np_i(1-p_i)\}$ diverges the sum of interest would also diverge. But if we were to find out that $\{np_i(1-p_i)\}$ converges, we would not be able to conclude on the divergence or convergence of the sum of interest. All the previous work was done to show that both divergence *and* convergence of it depend on what happens with $\{np_n(1-p_n)\}$:What is now needed is to examine whether $\{np_n(1-p_n)\}$ is Cauchy or not.